# Error upgrading database in WP: "Queue runner must be configured before execution

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Just upgraded to 5.27.3. Tried to upgrade database, got "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Queue runner must be configured before execution."

Any ideas what a "queue runner" is and how I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Got the same error on my production site... it works with my development environment on Mac but fails on basically the same wordpress site on my prod environment that runs on Ubuntu...

Comment: I've just restored the whole site with Updraft, then re-followed the CiviCRM upgrade instructions meticulously... Still getting this **Queue runner must be configured before execution** error. Clearly something wrong with the latest CiviCRM for Wordpress code.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a solution for this problem on a Drupal platform and decided to try it: you need to delete all the entries in the **civicrm_cache** table in your Wordpress database using phpmyadmin **before** you try and upgrade the database. This resolved the issue for me. Civi version 5.27.4

Comment: I did that, and still get the error... the funny thing is that it worked on my dev environment but not in my production ... however, now it does not work in either... Nothing I read about it worked... clearing the civicrm_cache table did not work either...